# Verify Auth0 token in Worker Cloudflare

Tags: javascript, jwt, auth0, cloudflare-workers

I'm using auth0 for login after successful login user gets access token, in some backend functions we need to verify token and if successful grant access to function otherwise reject it.
I copied public key from auth0 `dashboard->advanced settings->certificates` and this is my code:

```
const publicKey =`
    MIIDIzCC.....faMQkU`
    const options = {
    audience: ['clientID'],
    issuer: [
      'https://MYDOMAIN/',
    ],
    algorithms: ['RS256'],
  }
  const token =
    'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtp.....Nhe08A'

  jwt.verify(token, publicKey, options, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('jwt validation error', err)
    } else {
      console.log('verified token', decoded)
    }
  })
```

I only have error which says `error`
Anyone idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this package with a Cloudflare worker.

https://github.com/tsndr/cloudflare-worker-jwt#verify

No problem signing and verifying.
Install it like this:

```
npm i -D @tsndr/cloudflare-worker-jwt
```

and then just import it in your worker code.

```
import jwt from '@tsndr/cloudflare-worker-jwt'
```